# .grid adds unwanted height

Tags: html, css, jquery-masonry

I tried everything and searched for this issue but just can't resolve it.

It seems like that .grid has added an additional 100px which is undesired and messes with my layout. What did I do wrong?

shown the extra added height
[image]

[Link](http://www.pawelpietryka.com/www/)

`1px border` yellowbox: `.grid`

`1px border` greenbox: `.grid-item`

The CSS:

```
.grid {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 540px;
}
.grid-item {
    float: left;
    width: 246px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #bababa;
    padding-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

The JS

```
 $(document).ready( function() {

      $('.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: 250,
        gutter: 35
      });

});
```

Comment: What is your browser and its version?

Comment: Safari Version 9.0 (11601.1.56)

Comment: Chrome Version 47.0.2526.16 beta (64-bit)

Comment: I can't see your problem. [Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m on Windows 8](http://s15.postimg.org/ih3rml8nv/Capture.png)

Comment: Me either... you need to provide more code i think... take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ajx1upnx/

Comment: use Twitter Bootstrap, That will handle all the width and height issues for you.

Comment: thank you guys for looking into this, I don't know how to use that jsfiddle thing, does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/r6w1j70c/

Comment: If you are talking about that extra space in your jsfiddle.. then there is no way round that using your technique without using javascript. You can try using two colums that will fix your problems

Comment: its so weird, now Chrome is showing it correctly and Safari isn't. I haven't changed anything on the server. Phontonic, can you please elaborate or hint with a link how I could solve this, I mean is it really necessary to do this script if it happens in one place. Thanks!

Comment: I still dont understand whats is the problem... is it the extra 100px you mentioned from the start? So what is your purpose of using masony?

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm a super noob in CSS, I'm using masonry to close the space vertically between the .grid-items (the text has different lengths). I would hard code the position if I knew how, however I don't want to introduce 2 columns because I would like switch to one column layout for mobile (with media queries) thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try testing this code on every browser first. ->>>> http://jsfiddle.net/r6w1j70c/2/

All ive added is Jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

If it works on all your browser then it means that JS Masonry is not the problem... is your coding that might be messing it up.